# semisimple orbifold quantum cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Dubrovin conjecture says, roughly speaking, that the quantum cohomology of a variety $X$ is semisimple if and only if it is a good Fano [good means that there exits a full exceptional collection in the bounded derived category of coherent sheaves of $X$] If we consider not a variety but an orbifold $Y$ and orbifold quantum cohomology, Does there exist any criteria in order to determine whether the orbifold quantum cohomology of $Y$ is semisimple?

Comment: I don't understand how to build mirror pairs well enough to answer the question, but undoubtedly a closely related question is what does the mirror of your orbifold look like?